# Error when trying to encode/decode String to Base64

Tags: java, base64

I need to do Base64 encoding from byte array to stirng as opposed to another byte array. But when I decode it back I get exception. Here is the code

I'm trying to encode a byte array into a string using Base64 encoding. When I encode, it seems to work, but when I decode it throws an exception. What am I doing wrong?

```
import org.springframework.security.crypto.codec.Base64;

byte[] bytes = new byte[]{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
String stringToStore = Base64.encode(bytes).toString();
byte[] restoredBytes = Base64.decode(stringToStore.getBytes());
```

Here is the exception I'm getting:

```
org.springframework.security.crypto.codec.InvalidBase64CharacterException: Bad Base64 input character decimal 91 in array position 0
at org.springframework.security.crypto.codec.Base64.decode(Base64.java:625)
at org.springframework.security.crypto.codec.Base64.decode(Base64.java:246)
```

Comment: You should accept one of the answers, if it worked for you.

Answer (score 17):

Could you try...

```
byte[] bytes = new byte[]{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}; 
String stringToStore = new String(Base64.encode(bytes));
byte[] restoredBytes = Base64.decode(stringToStore.getBytes());
```

Answer (score 8):

`Base64.encode(bytes).toString()` does not return the String that you expect.

You should use

```
new String(Base64.encode(bytes))
```

as suggested by iccthedral.

Answer (score 3):

```
String stringToStore = Base64.encode(bytes).toString();
```

That's not turning the bytes to a string.  It's Java's string representation of the object (for example, `"[B@9a4d5c6"`).  You need to do what iccthedral suggest and provide the bytes to a String class.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Android API 8+ there's a `Base64` helper class in `android.util`.

```
String stringToStore =  Base64.encodeToString(cipherText, Base64.DEFAULT);
```

Answer (score 2):

Initially if you are using this for passwords, its not recommended to convert to Strings. To use as String follow the following code segment

```
    byte[] bytes = new byte[]{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
    String stringToStore = new String(Base64.encode(bytes), "UTF-8");
    byte[] restoredBytes = Base64.decode(stringToStore.getBytes());
```

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
        byte[] bytes = new byte[]{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9};
        String stringToStore = Base64.encode(bytes);
        //System.out.println(stringToStore);//AQIDBAUGBwgJ
        byte[] restoredBytes = Base64.decode(stringToStore);
        //System.out.println(Arrays.toString(restoredBytes));//[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

I have edited it a bit:

- Dont call `toString()` on a `String`. `encode(bytes)` method already returns a `String` (as noted by others calling this might be whats resulting in the error)
- Why convert to bytes when its not needed just more code (`Base64.decode(stringToStore.getBytes())`)

Comment: Can you please provide a link to your Base64 class whose encode() returns a String and not byte[]

Answer (score 0):

`Base64.decode()` appears to [return a `byte\[\]`](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/crypto/codec/Base64.html). Calling `toString()` gives you some default Java description of the array, nothing like "56AB0FC3...". You would need to do that conversion yourself.

Likewise your call to `getBytes()` is not doing at all what you think.

Answer (score 0):

I tried Base64 from  [apache codec](http://commons.apache.org/codec/download_codec.cgi) , and the result is fine.

```
    import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;
    byte[] bytes = new byte[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };
    Base64 base64 = new Base64();
    byte[] stringToStore = base64.encode(bytes);
    System.out.print(Arrays.toString(stringToStore));//[65, 81, 73, 68, 66, 65, 85, 71, 66, 119, 103, 74]
    byte[] restoredBytes = base64.decode(stringToStore);
    System.out.print(Arrays.toString(restoredBytes));//[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Answer (score 0):

To decode byte array which contais base64 content you can use *javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter*. It works pretty well. I use it to decode MongoDB values of binary type.

```
String testString = "hi, I'm test string";
byte[] byteArrayBase64 = org.apache.commons.codec.digest.DigestUtils.md5(testString);
String decoded = javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter.printBase64Binary(byteArrayBase64);
assert testString.equals(decoded);
```