# How to store images in MySQL server using android

Tags: android, sql, web-services, soap, camera

I'm creating a application using camera options in that one the captured images are stored in the MySQL server using soap web service.

I created a URL using Asp.net,the data type of the images are byte[],In my android coding I'm too convert image into byte[].The problem if i use

`request.add Property("Photo",image);`//image is the byte[] variable
//the above code using soap web service in android

it doesn't store in my sql server table.
How can i do that one?
Thanks in advance

Comment: I've done this before by sending images to server but with php as backend

Comment: Thanks for the response,I tried in soap web service using c#

Answer (score 0):

What you have to do is convert that byte array into a string, and then you store the string in your database. Then, when you retrieve it, you will convert it back into a byte array, and then into a bitmap.

[Error when trying to encode/decode String to Base64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12300561/base64-encoding-from-byte-array-to-string-what-do-i-do-wrong)

Comment: Thanks for th link..but In MySQL server the image data type is in byte[],so I can't send the image in string.In case of decode also in byte[] the server won't accept.

Comment: So you are sending/recieving byte arrays?

Comment: Is there a readon you can't store strings instead? In the case that you have to store byte[], you might have to convert byte[] to dtring, send to server, and have th server convert that string to a byte[] and store it. Not sure how youcan send byte][ directly, though.

Comment: Thanks for your reply..But convert byte[] to string that string can't store in SQLserver then how can I convert string to byte[].

Comment: I'm not sure, to be honest. You'll have to look up "how to convert string to byte[] in ______" with whatever language you are using on the back end of the server